# how to fix non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, netbeans

i have this string declaration in a class

```
String username,ICNo,studentID,password;
```

and i have this method that reads from a txt file therefore assigning variables it got from the string

```
static void createFound(String ID){
        try {File myObj = new File(infoFile);
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(myObj);
      boolean notFound=true;
      while (sc.hasNextLine()&&notFound) {
        String data = sc.nextLine();
        String[] userInfo = data.split(Character.toString(seperator));
        if(userInfo[2].equals(ID)){
            notFound=false;
            username=userInfo[0];
            ICNo=userInfo[1];
            studentID=userInfo[2];
            password=findPass(userInfo[0]);
            
           // System.out.println(foundUser.username);


        }
   
      }
      sc.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("An error occurred.");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

i have an error here (non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context) on line

```
username=userInfo[0];
ICNo=userInfo[1];
studentID=userInfo[2];
password=findPass(userInfo[0]);
```

i have trird adding static declaration to the line where i declare my variables but found that if i do in that way it returns a blank when i do this

```
jLabel9.setText(student.studentID);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the static from method createFound() or make the variables static.